# Sitecore Content Editor generates Random GUI element properties or which are not unique on webpage like xPath, ID or Class

Tags: xpath, automation, sitecore, ui-automation, sitecore8.2

While automating Sitecore Content editor (backend) i have come across one problem that, while adding the same component, values of element ID's and xPath changes. Elements like add here or approve button etc.
I would like to know if there is a way while developing the components we can render the element properties (GUI properties like xPath, ID or Class) in specific pattern or if components can be generated with the same element values like ID or xPath.
GUI properties are used in element identification on GUI and if they change everytime scripts always fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Sync the Sitecore Items, there are some great tools like Unicorn(Free) and TDS from (hedgehog), or you should use the Sitecore Packages to move items between instances(not for development).

If you want to just create  or access the Item Properties you can always access them through Sitecore Powershell module: [SitecorePowershell](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items)